equivalent of numpy.roll() for pandas Series
I have a pandas Series:
In[1]: b1.data
Out[1]: 
z        40.0
R         0.0
DET       6.9
FAEac    16.0
Name: SC3, dtype: object


and I'm trying to move the 'z' row to the bottom of the Series.
If that was a numpy.array I'd simply do:
numpy.roll(b1.data, -1)

but working with pandas Series the one-liner I came up with is:
In[2]: pandas.concat([b1.data,pandas.Series(b1.data.pop('z'),index=['z'])])
Out[2]: 
R         0.0
DET       6.9
FAEac    16.0
z        40.0
dtype: object
    

Isn't there a less cumbersome way to achieve the same?

Code
example
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'z': 40.0, 'R': 0.0, 'DET': 6.9, 'FAEac': 16.0}
s = pd.Series(data)

code
Put the result of rolling the index in square brackets
out = s[np.roll(s.index, -1)]

result
z        40.0           R         0.0
R         0.0           DET       6.9
DET       6.9      ->   FAEac    16.0
FAEac    16.0           z        40.0
   s                         out


Not working for duplicated index values pd.Series(data).rename({'FAEac':'z'})

@jezrael I think answered well for the sample of questioners, and I don't think necessarily need to assume duplicate indexes because it's a bad habit of handling data in and of itself (though there are many ways to handle it, and it's not that hard).

Sure, I think only missing description in answer, there should be mentioned it working only for unique index values.

Use Series constructor:
out = pandas.Series(numpy.roll(b1.data, -1), index=numpy.roll(b1.data.index, -1))

Or use Series.iloc for change positions - working e.g. for duplicated index values:
out = b1.data.iloc[np.roll(np.arange(len(b1.data)), -1)]
print (out)
R         0.0
DET       6.9
FAEac    16.0
z        40.0
Name: data, dtype: float64

Test for duplicated values of index:
print (b1.data)
z      40.0
R       0.0
DET     6.9
z      16.0
Name: data, dtype: float64

out = b1.data.iloc[np.roll(np.arange(len(b1.data)), -1)]
print (out)
R       0.0
DET     6.9
z      16.0
z      40.0
Name: data, dtype: float64


out = pd.Series(np.roll(b1.data, -1), index=np.roll(b1.data.index, -1))
print (out)
R       0.0
DET     6.9
z      16.0
z      40.0
dtype: float64


thanks @jezrael, but the second solution does not shift the indices!

@user2078621 - yop, removed second solution

@user2078621 - added general solution for duplicated index values with iloc
